# String comparison of Boolean value in Python

Tags: python, json, yaml

If I have a Yaml like below -

```
Drives:
   Drive: Local
          Default:  true
   Drive: Remote 
          Default: false
```

And I read this in Python to do Boolean comparison as string -

```
If Env_obj.get(“default”, “false”) != “true”:
Do something
```

Is this good? Should you eval the Boolean first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is your YAML seems to be in invalid format (you can check via a validator like [this one](http://www.yamllint.com/))

Here's a solution using the [`PyYAML`](https://pypi.org/project/PyYAML/) library in Python for reading YAML. No need to convert string to boolean, as this should already be done.

```py
from io import StringIO

import yaml

yaml_data = StringIO("""
---
Drives:
  -
    Default: true
    Drive: Local
  -
    Default: false
    Drive: Remote
""")

d = yaml.load(yaml_data, yaml.Loader)

d
# {'Drives': [{'Default': True, 'Drive': 'Local'}, {'Default': False, 'Drive': 'Remote'}]}

default = d['Drives'][0]['Default']

default, type(default)
# True <class 'bool'>
```